# Amazon RDS Unable to connect to the database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to connect to Amazon RDS through Eclipse AWS Elastic Beanstalk, probably is because I am using a Proxy, but I don't know where to define it.

> Unable to connect to the database.  Make sure your password is correct and make sure you can access your database through your network and any firewalls you may be connecting through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your AWS VPC configuration. The security-group will need to be adjusted to allow you to connect from a new source/port.

1. Find the security Group-id for the RDS.
2. Find that group in AWS Console > VPC > secuirty groups
3. Adjust the Inbound and Outbound Rules accordingly.

   - You need to allow access to/from the IP or security group that needs to connect to the RDS.