# Access an RDS instance created in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When you set up a new Elastic Beanstalk cluster you can access your EC2 instance by doing this:

```
eb ssh
```

However, it's not clear how to access the RDS instance.

How do you access an RDS in an Elastic Beanstalk context in order to perform CRUD operations?

Comment: you can't access an RDS instance with SSH or get a shell on it.

Comment: What I mean is gain access too the RDS in order to perform CRUD operations. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDS command-line can be accessed from anywhere, by adjusting the RDS security group.

> ### Check your AWS VPC configuration.
>
> The security-group will need to be
> adjusted to allow you to connect from a new source/port.
>
> 1. Find the security Group-id for the RDS.
> 2. Find that group in AWS Console > VPC > secuirty groups
> 3. Adjust the Inbound and Outbound Rules accordingly.
>
>    - You need to allow access to/from the IP or security group that needs to connect to the RDS.

FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37200075/1589379

After that, all that remains is configuring whatever local DB tool you would like to use to operate on the database.

**EDIT:**

Of additional note, if the ElasticBeanstalk Environment is configured to use RDS, the EC2 Instances will have environment variables set with the information needed to connect to the RDS.

This means that you can import those variables into any code that needs access.

Custom environment variables may also be set in Elastic Beanstalk Environment Configuration, and these too may be included this way.

#### PHP

```
define('RDS_HOSTNAME', getenv('RDS_HOSTNAME'));
$db = new rds(RDS_HOSTNAME);
```

#### Linux CommandLine

```
mysql --host=$RDS_HOSTNAME --port=$RDS_PORT -u $RDS_USERNAME -p$RDS_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 1):

RDS is a managed database service, which means it is that you can only access it through database calls.

If it is a MySQL database you can access through your EC2 instance through mysql like this:

```
mysql -u user -p password -h rds.instance.endpoint.region.rds.amazonaws.com
```

or set it up to work with your app with settings needed for that.

Make sure that you set up security groups correctly so that your EC2/other service has access to your RDS instance.

**Update**:
If you want what you are asking for then you should use an EC2 instance with a mysql server on. It would cost the same (even though a fraction of performance is lost in comparison). An EC2 instance you can turn off when you are not using as well.

Comment: Yes, it is MySQL that I am using. This solution means that I would have to install mysql (or at least the client) on my EC2 instance. I dont want to do that. I want to be able to access the database from my laptop.

Comment: Then it sounds as if you should use an EC2 instance with a mysql server on. It would cost the same (even though a fraction of performance is lost in comparison). An EC2 instance you can turn off when you are not using as well.

Comment: I am setting up a relatively complicated web application that needs to run in a clustered (Elastic Beanstalk) environment with a dedicated database server. I simply want to be able to manually read and write to the database.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for then. RDS sounds as the exact thing you want with a mysql client (or Mysql Workbench) on your laptop, possibly in a Vagrant virtual machine.

Depending on what type of web app you could probably set it up with sqlite for development as well.

Comment: 1) Use the magic of Elastic Beanstalk and RDS (including `eb ssh`)

2) Access my RDS MySql from my desktop